# How to implement listagg function in hibernate 5.0.1 without using native query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working in the spring boot 1.5 project.
I implemented listagg but I am getting "Unexcepted token error WITHIN " Please help me to implement listagg in hibernate without using native query.

```
Output:
    jobname     Empno
    AC_ACCOUNT  206
    AC_MGR      205
    AD_ASST     200
    AD_PRES     100
    AD_VP       101,102
    FI_ACCOUNT  110 ,113 ,111 ,109 ,112

select  jobname, listagg(empno, ',') within group (order by empno) empno
  from emp group by jobname;
```

-

```
unexpected token: within","stack_trace":"antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: within
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.aliasedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2365)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectedPropertiesList(HqlBaseParser.java:1379)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1282)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1022)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:730)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:186)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:279)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1907)
at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use listagg in hibernate query:

1. First register listagg function in Hibernate Dialect by extending Oracle10gDialect(in case you are using Oracle) or MySQLDialect(for MySQL)
   `public class CustomOracle10gDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
    public CustomOracle10gDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("LISTAGG", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING,"LISTAGG(?1,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ?1)"));
       }
   }`
2. Update your config file to use custom dialect. spring.jpa.database-platform=com.abc.CustomOracle10gDialect or com.abc.CustomOracle10gDialect
3. Use LISTAGG() Example - select c.id, listagg(firstName) from Contacts c where GROUP BY c.id

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid but this is not possible. Neither JPA nor Hibernate know listagg.

You must use SQL.

The reason is JPA and Hibernate have implemented features that run on all databases but listagg is only implemented by a few.

Comment: Thanks for your response